# What's the difference between f"{x}" and "{}".format(x) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format

I'm new to python, and I just want to know the difference between those examples.
Does it differ when it comes to the execution speed?

When do I use one of them instead of the other?

```
x: int = 64
print(f"Your Number is {x}")
```

and

```
x: int = 64
txt = "Your Number is {}"
print(txt.format(x))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The docs on [*each* of these](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) are several pages. Did you read them already? Are you interested in any *specific* case that would clear up what answers can *focus* on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python f-strings were added in 3.6. Therefore you should consider using format() if you need compatibility with earlier versions. Otherwise, use f-strings.

On macOS 12.1 running 3 GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W and Python 3.10.2, f-strings are significantly faster (~60%)

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference, technically speaking. The `f-string` format is recommended because it is more recent: it was introduced in Python 3.6. RealPython [explains](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#speed) that `f-strings` are faster than `str.format()`.

With `f-strings` the syntax is less verbose. Suppose you have the following variables:

```py
first_name = "Eric"
last_name = "Idle"
age = 74
profession = "comedian"
affiliation = "Monty Python"
```

This is how you would format a `str.format()` statement.

```py
print(("Hello, {name} {surname}. You are {age}. " + 
       "You are a {profession}. You were a member of {affiliation}.") \
       .format(name=first_name, surname=last_name, age=age,\
               profession=profession, affiliation=affiliation))
```

With formatting strings, it is considerably shortened:

```py
print(f"Hello {first_name} {last_name}. You are {age}" +
      f"You are a {profession}. You were a member of {affiliation}.")
```

Not only that: formatting strings offer a lot of nifty tricks, because they are evaluated at runtime:

```py
>>> name="elvis" # note it is lowercase
>>> print(f"WOW THAT IS {name.upper()}")
'WOW THAT IS ELVIS'
```

This can be done inside a `str.format(...)` statement too, but `f-strings` make it cleaner and less cumbersome. Plus, you can also specify [formatting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxUxX1Ku1EQ) inside the curly braces:

```py
>>> value=123
>>> print(f"{value=}")
'value = 123'
```

Which normally you should have written as `print("value = {number}".format(number=value))`. Also, you can evaluate expressions:

```
>>> print(f"{value % 2 =}")
'value % 2 = 1`
```

And also format numbers:

```py
>>> other_value = 123.456
>>> print(f"{other_value:.2f}") # will just print up to the second digit
'123.45'
```

And dates:

```py
>>> from datetime.datetime import now
>>> print(f"{now=:%Y-%m-%d}")
'now=2022-02-02'
```

Comment: Why is it recommended?

Comment: I have extended the answer with examples, but basically it is less verbose, cleaner and faster because it is evaluated at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Well, personally I use f string all the time, except when I'm dealing with floats or things like that, that require a specific formatting, that's when using .format is more suitable.

But if you are not dealing with text that require a specific formatting you should use f string, its easier to read.

Comment: Note that f-strings also support float format specifiers as ``.format`` does.